# Seeking CSS wizard...unruly inline CSS div/class/style in iOS webView

Tags: iphone, css, webview

This question is being re-phrased because some questions simply need to be re-written

How does one override the widths of these p tags? The content is spilling outside the bounds of my window, and that is unacceptable. I can not edit the html (generated by SharePoint), only overpower it with CSS. :

```
<div class="ms-rteElement-photodivright" style="width:475px">
<p class="ms-rteStyle-photoCredit">this text spills over my desired width</p>
<p class="ms-rteStyle-photocaption">This text spills over my desired width</p>
</div>
```

This is what I've got:

```
div#wrapper
 { 
margin:0 auto !important; 
width:%f !important; 
background:green;
 float:left !important; 
 position: relative !important;
}
body 
{
  background:darkgreen !important;
 }

.clear
 {
clear:both !important;
}
img 
{max-width:%f !important; 
height:auto;
} 
div [class] 
{
p: width:%f !important; 
float:clear !important;
}
 .override div.ms-rteElement-photodivright
 {
max-width:%f 
!important; 
margin:auto;
}

.override p.ms-rteStyle-photocaption 
{
max-width:%f !important; 
margin:auto;
}
```

Here is a result: You see the differing shades of green? I want the content that is spilling into the dark shades of green to stay contained in the green (my wrapper)... The content that is spilling over are these P classes in the code above... 
[image]

Thank you

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. "I need to know how to completely overwhelm sort of code you will find in the data I'm working with"... what does that mean? Are you asking how to make CSS rules that will override absolutely everything else?

Comment: Sure you can remove the offending bits of HTML. Just use Javascript/DOM manipulation to nuke the inline `style` attributes. (I'm assuming that if you can add stylesheets to the web view you can add scripts.)

Comment: This is being done on XCode for a webView. See bold text in center of question. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know it, I answered my own question...

```
 .ms-rteElement-photodivright
 {
 max-width:%f 
 !important; 
 margin:auto;
 }

.ms-rteStyle-photocaption 
{
max-width:%f !important; 
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if your wrapper needs `position: relative;` as from what I can tell your images have absolute position. They will position / measure themselves against the first container above them in the cascade which has relative, absolute or fixed position. It's a bit difficult without a working example, though.

Comment: I appreciate that you have helped me despite there being no working example. Its just a terrible mess, and I really just want to know how to override the div and p classes above, as I can not remove them from my code.

Comment: The question has been re worded.

Comment: I've added results and my stylesheet.